# regex matching in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to extract a portion of text that is embedded within parenthesis in a text string:

```
"Dominion Diamond Corporation (DDC) "
```

(I want to extract DDC).

Perusing the interwebs suggests that the regular expression

```
"\([^)]*\)"
```

will be useful.

I try the following:

```
ret = Regex(regExp)
match(ret, "Dominion Diamond Corporation (DDC) ")
```

Output:

```
RegexMatch("Dominion Diamond Corporation (DDC", 1="Dominion Diamond Corporation (DDC")
```

However, when i enter the regex expression into the match function directly:

```
match(r"\([^)]*\)"t, "Dominion Diamond Corporation (DDC) ")
```

The output is:

```
RegexMatch("(DDC)")
```

Why / how are these two expressions different? How do I interpolate an arbitrary regex expression into the first arg for match?

Comment: `r"string"` usually means raw string (i.e. Python). I suspect it was stripping the backslashes before. I have no clue why there's a `t` at the end, though.

Comment: looking back at my notebook, I think the "t" was a copy / paste error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Laurel suggests in a comment, the single backslashes weren't making it through to the `match` function.

```
julia> rstring = "\\([^)]*\\)"
"\\([^)]*\\)"

julia> match(Regex(rstring), "Dominion Diamond Corporation (DDC) ")
RegexMatch("(DDC)")
```

Comment: thank you; probably should thought of this initially.

Comment: Just to add, in Julia, `r"..."` means "construct RegEx with ...", so backslashes are preserved for convenience.