# RegEx for matching if a line contains special characters in Julia

Tags: regex, julia

file app_ids.txt is of the following format:

```
app1 = "0123456789"
app2 = "1234567890"
app3 = "2345678901"
app4 = "3456789012"
app5 = "4567890123"
```

printing the lines containing the given regex with the following code in file, find_app_id.jl:

```
#! /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/bin/julia

function find_app_id()
   app_pattern = "r\"app2.*\"i"
    open("/path/to/app_ids.txt", "r") do apps
        for app in eachline(apps)
            if occursin(app_pattern, app)
                println(app)
            end
         end
    end
end
find_app_id()
```

$/home/julia/find_app_id.jl, does not print the second line though it contains the regex!

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: with reference to bob jarvis advice, app_pattern = Regex("app2.*") instead of app_pattern =  "r\"app2\"i"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression looks odd. If you change the line which assigns to `app_pattern` to

```
app_pattern = r"app2.*"
```

it should work better.

For example, the following prints "Found it" when run:

```
app_pattern = r"app2.*"
if occursin(app_pattern, "app2 = blah-blah-blah")
  println("Found it")
else
  println("Nothing there")
end
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, how regex matching works in Julia, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694571/regex-matching-in-julia) might help you to figure it out.

However, in general, your pattern is quite simple, and you probably do not need regular expression matching to do this task.

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/a0PeMd/1/) might help you to design your expression.

```
^app[0-9]+\s=\s\x22([0-9]+)\x22$
```

There is a simple `([0-9]+)` in the middle where your desired app ids are, and you can simply call them using `$1`:

[image]

This graph shows how the expression would work:

[image]